# GatsbyJS cannot find module 'fs' webpack config issue

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I'm using `gatsby` for a small application. So far it worked fine, but after I installed some additional `npm`-modules I get two errors `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in...`

Since `gatsby` runs on `webpack` and there is no `webpack.config.js`-file where you might change your setup, Gatsby recommends to add a [custom webpack config file](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/docs/docs/add-custom-webpack-config.md).

From further research it seems that adding this to the webpack config file

```
node: {
 fs: "empty"
}
```

would solve the problem. So, I tried to add thsi to my `gatsby-node.js` file:

```
exports.modifyWebpackConfig = () => {
    node: {
       fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

but it solved nothing and I still get the same errors. Does anyone experience the same issue or does someone maybe have an solution for this?

thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're using an NPM package that's not intended to be used in the browser. See if you can find an alternative package.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following to `gatsby-node.js` solved the issue for me in Gatsby V2:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    node: { fs: 'empty' },
  })
}
```